# how to update or add new row in a datatable from another datatable

Tags: asp.net, datatables-1.10

how to update  a  datatable  from another datatable  with same column  if  a column name "station" match in first datatable then update other value .If "station" column is not exist then add new row datatable1 and copy the data from datatable2

```
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        DataSet ds1 = new DataSet();

        ds1.ReadXml(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("XML/myFile.xml"));
        DataTable dt1 = ds1.Tables[0];


        //dt1.Merge(dt);
        //dt1.AcceptChanges();

        //DataView dw = new DataView(dt);
        //DataTable dt2 = dw.ToTable(true, "DateTime", "Station", "Max_Temp", "Min_Temp", "Weather_Detail");


        for (int i = 0; i <= dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j <= dt1.Rows.Count; j++)
            //{
                if (dt1.Rows[i]["Station"].ToString().Contains(dt.Rows[i]["Station"].ToString()))
                {
                    //&& dt1.Rows[i]["Max_Temp"].ToString() == dt.Rows[j]["Max_Temp"].ToString() && dt1.Rows[i]["Station"].ToString() == dt.Rows[j]["Station"].ToString())

                    dt1.Rows[i]["Max_Temp"] = dt.Rows[i]["Max_Temp"];
                    dt1.Rows[i]["Min_Temp"] = dt.Rows[i]["Min_Temp"];

                    dt1.Rows[i]["Weather_Detail"] = dt.Rows[i]["Weather_Detail"];
                    dt1.Rows[i]["DateTime"] = dt.Rows[i]["DateTime"];

                }
                else
                {
                    DataRow dr = null;


                    dr = dt1.NewRow();
                    dt1.Rows.Add(dr);
                    dt1.Rows[i]["Station"]= dt.Rows[i]["Station"].ToString();
                    dt1.Rows[i]["Max_Temp"] = dt.Rows[i]["Max_Temp"];
                    dt1.Rows[i]["Min_Temp"] = dt.Rows[i]["Min_Temp"];

                    dt1.Rows[i]["Weather_Detail"] = dt.Rows[i]["Weather_Detail"];
                    dt1.Rows[i]["DateTime"] = dt.Rows[i]["DateTime"];

                }
            }
            dt1.AcceptChanges();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

the below is the sample code please Check and verify.

```
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        DataSet ds1 = new DataSet();

        ds.ReadXml(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("XMLFile1.xml"));
        DataTable dt1 = ds.Tables[0];

        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {                
                if (dt1.Rows[i]["Station"].ToString().Contains(dt.Rows[i]["Station"].ToString()))
                {
                    dt1.Rows[i]["Max_Temp"] = dt.Rows[i]["Max_Temp"];
                    dt1.Rows[i]["Min_Temp"] = dt.Rows[i]["Min_Temp"];

                    dt1.Rows[i]["Weather_Detail"] = dt.Rows[i]["Weather_Detail"];
                    dt1.Rows[i]["DateTime"] = dt.Rows[i]["DateTime"];
                }
                else
                {
                    DataRow dr;
                    dr = dt1.NewRow();
                    dr["Station"] = dt.Rows[i]["Station"].ToString();
                    dr["Max_Temp"] = dt.Rows[i]["Max_Temp"];
                    dr["Min_Temp"] = dt.Rows[i]["Min_Temp"];
                    dr["Weather_Detail"] = dt.Rows[i]["Weather_Detail"];
                    dr["DateTime"] = dt.Rows[i]["DateTime"];
                    dt1.Rows.Add(dr);

            }
            dt1.AcceptChanges();

        }
```